# Move to the next iteration one at time

Tags: javascript, algorithm, iteration

I have variable called current which stores number 0 and array with the length of 4 I want to iterate the array then add it to current variable one at time if the the first one don't pass move to the next one how can I achieve that please help !!! for example:

```
    /*2 0
      7 0
      11 0
      15 0*/

if not try the next one:

  /*2 1
    7 1
    11 1
    15 1*/
so on and so forth

let nums = [2,7,11,15]
let target = 18
let current = 0

nums.forEach(function(k,i){
let begin = current
if(nums[begin]+nums[i] === target){
  console.log(true)
}else{
begin++
}
console.log(nums[begin],nums[i])

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let nums    = [2,7,11,15]
  , target  = 18
  , flag=0
  , i, j
  ;
for( i=0; i<nums.length-1; i++) {
  for( j=i+1; j<nums.length; j++) {
    if((nums[i]+nums[j])===target) {
        flag=1;
        break;
     }
  }
  if(flag) break;
}
console.log(nums[i],nums[j]);
```

Comment: Great, if this works please do give an upvote @Aliayub Ali

Answer (score 0):

that ?

```js
let nums    = [2,7,11,15]
  , target  = 18
  , i, j, found = false
  ;
for(i=0; i<nums.length-1; i++) {
  for( j=i+1; j<nums.length; j++) {
    found = (nums[i]+nums[j])===target 
    if (found) break;
  }
  if (found) break;
}
if (found) console.log('values = ', nums[i],'+', nums[j], '=', target )
else       console.log('none' )
```

You can also do that:

```js
let nums    = [2,7,11,15]
  , target  = 18
  , i=0, j=1, sum = nums[i] + nums[j]
  ;
while (sum != target)
  {
  if (++j===nums.length )
    if (++i===(nums.length-1)) break
    else j=i+1
  sum = nums[i] + nums[j]
  }

if (sum===target) console.log('values = ', nums[i],'+', nums[j], '=', target )
else              console.log('none' )
```